# short technique to get the value of multiple input

Tags: php

guys just wondering if there is a better style of coding to get the multiple input from the from cuz i think my coding is too long and eat a lot of lines

```
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="number_students" value="4">  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[0]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="grade[0]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[1]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="grade[1]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[2]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="grade[2]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[3]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="grade[3]"></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="submit_in" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

php..

```
$button = $_POST['submit_in'];
$arrayname = array();
$arraygrade = array();
$name= $_POST['name'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];   
$counter2 = 0;


if(isset($button)){

    foreach($name as $a => $x){ 
        $arrayname[] ="".$x;
        }  
 foreach($grade as $b => $y){
            $arraygrade[] ="".$y;
            $counter2+=1;
        }  
        for($v=0;$v<=$counter2-1;$v++){
            $insert = "INSERT INTO stud_info(stud_name,stud_grade) 
          VALUES('$arrayname[$v]','$arraygrade[$v]')";
          if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
            die('error insert'.mysql_error());
        }

        }


}
```

i wonder if there is a cleaner technique to get those values, assuming that the inputs are dynamic thats why I input an array at the end of the names and ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing a query in a loop is not a good thing too do, it will slow down your execution. 
Try this:

```
    if(!empty($_POST)) {

        //check if post variables are set and they are not empty

        //check that sizeof($_POST['name']) == $_POST['grade']

        //connect to db

        $name = $grade = array();
        for($i=0; $i < sizeof($_POST['name']); ++$i) { 
            $name[$i] = mysql_real_eascape_string(trim($_POST['name'][$i]));
            $grade[$i] = mysql_real_eascape_string(trim($_POST['grade'][$i]));
        } 

        $values = array();
        $insert = 'INSERT INTO stud_info(`stud_name`, `stud_grade`) VALUES';
        for($i=0; $i < sizeof($name); ++$i) { 
            $values[$i] = '(\''.$name[$i].'\', \''.$grade[$i].'\')';
        }
        $values = implode(', ', $values);
        $insert .= $values;

        if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
            die('error insert'.mysql_error());
        }

    }
```

Comment: uhmmm. would can you make an explanation of the codes. thats so advance for me, so its kinda hard to digest inside my brain. haha.

Comment: Ok, well the main idea is to make only one query to update the database. To do that your query have to look like this:
INSERT INTO stud_info(`stud_name`, `stud_grade`) VALUES
('name1', '5'), ('name2', '8'), ('name6', '7')

Comment: So you create an array named $values with elements like this ('name1', '5') or ('name2', '8') and then implode them with ', ' between them. Implode function create a string with all the elements of an array adding while a string between all of them

Comment: So you have a string like ('name1', '5'), ('name2', '8'), ('name6', '7') and then you just concatenate it with the 'INSERT INTO stud_info(`stud_name`, `stud_grade`) VALUES'.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not required because php return a array for multipal  inputs you dont need to create a different ,$post is already array and also $post["name"] is array

```
      $name = $_POST['name']; 

       foreach( $name as $key => $n ) { echo "The name is ".$n.".", thank you\n"; }
```

See its already a array you dont need to loop and create it again
Its already there

When you do $name=$_post["name"]; 
$name becomes array in your case

As simple as that

$button = $_POST['submit_in']; 
$name= $_POST['name'];
 $grade = $_POST['grade']; 
$counter2 = 0;

if(isset($button)){

for($v=0;$v<=$counter2-1;$v++){ $insert = "INSERT INTO stud_info(stud_name,stud_grade) VALUES('$name[$v]','$grade[$v]')"; if(@!mysql_query($insert)){ die('error insert'.mysql_error()); }

}

}

**NOTE ** I AM ON MOBOLE BROWSER SO CODE IS NOT TESTED BUT IT SHOUL WORK

Comment: yes its working. but is there a better way?. i find messy to use and consumes a lot of lines

Comment: So you want to have some code written for you or do you have a specific issue?

Comment: i want to have some codes. i have an idea of calling the name[0] and the index inside will increment so theres no need to put it in array but my skill is insufficient. ahahaha..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also worry more about security and SQL Injection from your code ...

#### Revisited PHP Code (10 lines)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stud_info(stud_name,stud_grade)  VALUES('%s','%s')" ;
if (isset($_POST['submit_in'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
    {
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]);
        $grade = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['grade'][$i]);
        $insert = sprintf($sql, $name, $grade);
        mysql_query($insert) or die('error insert' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: im just in the start of creating it, when im done ill be doing that. but thanks for reminding me.